# Tag or Tags for water-sports Request

Tags: support

I'd like to ask questions related with water-sports.

Could you create new tag for water-sports?
I see there exists tags like snow/winter-sports.

It would be even nicer to create more specific sport tags, like: windsurfing, kitesuring ... or for winter-sports skiing, snowboarding etc...
But for beginning, just request for "water-sports" tag, please :).

Comment: Can you mention, what question should we use to add this tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood, you wanted to mark this question:

[Windsurfing in Switzerland (or nearby areas)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8706/windsurfing-at-switzerland)

I created the tag [water-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-sports), and [windsurfing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windsurfing) as synonym